# F# pass multidimensional array of bool to function

Tags: f#

How can I pass a multdimensional array of bools to a function in F#?

Thanks 
Maybettle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two options depending on whether you're using actual 2D array (rectangular array) or jagged array (an array whose elements are arrays, with possibly different length):

If you're not sure which one to use, then it is good to know that jagged arrays are faster, but it may be easier to work with rectangular arrays (because you're sure about the dimensions).

```
let foo (ar:bool[,]) = ar.[0, 0]   // Get element at specified coordinates
let bar (ar:bool[][]) = ar.[0].[0] // Get first array and then the element
```

To call the two functions, you can use the following syntax:

```
// Create array of arrays and call the function
bar [| [| true |] |]

// Creates array of arrays and converts it to multi-dimensional array
// You can also use plenty of functions from 'Array2D' module
foo (array2D [| [| true |] |])
```

If you want to write function that will be more general, you can also use sequence of sequences. This will be compatible with jagged arrays only, but you can also use the function with e.g. F# lists of lists or any .NET collection types.

```
let woo (ar:seq<#seq<bool>>) = Seq.head (Seq.head ar)
```

The `#seq<..>` type means that it can be sequence or any other derived type. This is needed for the element type, but not for the outer type, because F# automatically casts the outer type (but not elements).